# How safe or unsafe is the attribute whose value is "passwod" in the input element?

Tags: html

Is it possible to retrieve data which is typed in the password input field?

```
<input type="password" name="password" class="inputbox" />
```

If so how?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by retrieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After typing your password, if you right click, then "Inspect a source element" (on Chrome) on your password input, you can change the type to "text", which will reveal the password.

However, you should not consider that your page/site is unsafe because you use password type input. That's a HTML standard. The part which has to be safe and secured is the PHP code which will deal with the login/subscribe, or the database which will store the password.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that's special about the `password` input is that it masks its content **visually** with asterisks or dots. It does not offer any other protection over regular text inputs,* it's not a "secure" input in any way. All it marginally protects from are shoulder surfers.

* It *may* restrict copy/pasting, but that's hardly worth mentioning in the grand scheme of things.